# UItextView Space on nextline event

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextview, uitextviewdelegate

i have UITextView with lines. here i added text in UITextView, while i click the next line button(return/enter) ,The text start printing  before the margin .but the text should start after the margin, so i want to leave space before the text, when i entered the next line event.

**Here is my code below**

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{

  if ([text isEqualToString:@"\n"])
  {
     note.text=[note.text stringByAppendingString:@"           "];
  }
  NSLog(@"%@",text);
  return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{

  if ([text isEqualToString:@"\n"])
  {
     note.text=[note.text stringByAppendingString:@"\n           "];
     return NO;
  }
  NSLog(@"%@",text);
  return YES;
}
```

Comment: You can use delegate: - (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView

Comment: but when i type a word at last in a line ,if the characters exceeds then it will go before the margin only. not coming as lik that new line text position. how to solve that

Comment: Try to call method when you programmatically changing text of textview: - (void)textViewDidChangeSelection:(UITextView *)textView

Comment: couldn't get idea to do in this (void)textViewDidChangeSelection:(UITextView *)textView       can u tell little briefly

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21127/discussion-between-raaj-and-omk)